# Check password against Linux shadow file in ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, bash

I want to get a password from the running user and check it against the /etc/shadow file in Linux to see if this is indeed the right password or not, I tried to use %x with some bash calls and get the exit status but apparently this isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
print "Enter current user password: "
system ("stty -echo")
pass = gets.chomp
system ("stty echo")
system("history -c")
%x(su root << EOF\n#{pass}\n\rEOF)

status = $?.exitstatus
until status == 0 do
        print "\nWrong password, type again: "
        system ("stty -echo")
        pass = gets.chomp
        system ("stty echo")
        %x(su root << EOF\n#{pass}\nEOF)
        status = $?.exitstatus
end
```

Comment: So, found an options which is not viable, rpam gem (which is broken for now)

Comment: Looking around, PAM seems to be a good option. Is it a requirement that you use ruby? [This question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28812/is-it-possible-to-test-user-name-and-password) looks relevant to you. You could also use [this ruby gem](https://github.com/mogest/unix-crypt) and compare the result of the attempt with the value in `/etc/shadow`.